# Array not removing elements correctly swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

In my application I am using a tableView to showcase options on where to go out on a date. For this I have a couple `groups` and `subgroups`.

The groups and subgroups are:

```
var mainGroups : [String] = ["Out On The Town", "Night In"]
let subGroups : [String] = ["Restaurants", "Activities", "Laid Back"]
let restaurantSubGroups : [String] = ["Dining", "Fast Food", "Desserts"]
```

So if the `Restaurant` cell is clicked, it will append `mainGroup`, create cells with the `restaurantSubGroup` strings underneath, and if clicked again, it will delete those cells.

For deleting, I check if the cell has been clicked before. If it has, I remove the restaurantSubGroups strings form the mainGroup and update the cells accordingly. Pretty simple right?

The problem occurs with the array. For a reason that I cannot find, it removes, `dining` and `desserts` from the array, but skips over `Fast Food` and removes `Laid Back` instead.

Here is the code:

```
//Bools declared as class variables
var outOnTheTownIsActive : Bool = false
var restaurantIsActive : Bool = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(mainGroups[indexPath.row])"

    if mainGroups.contains((cell.textLabel?.text)!) {
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    }
    if subGroups.contains((cell.textLabel?.text)!) {
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    }
    if restaurantSubGroups.contains((cell.textLabel?.text)!) || activitySubGroups.contains((cell.textLabel?.text)!) || laidbackSubGroups.contains((cell.textLabel?.text)!) {
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let cellText = cell?.textLabel?.text

    switch cellText {
    case "Out On The Town":
        print("\(String(describing: cell?.textLabel?.text)) is clicked and row is \(indexPath.row)")
        if outOnTheTownIsActive {
            alterArray(starting: 2, ending: 4)
            addDeleteCells(starting: 1, ending: 3, indexPath: indexPath, add: false)
            outOnTheTownIsActive = false
        } else {
            mainGroups.insert(contentsOf: subGroups, at: indexPath.row+1)
            addDeleteCells(starting: 1, ending: 3, indexPath: indexPath, add: true)
            outOnTheTownIsActive = true
        }

    case "Restaurants":
       // print("\(String(describing: cell?.textLabel?.text)) is clicked and row is \(indexPath.row)")
        if restaurantIsActive {
            print("The items in the array are \(mainGroups) and i am removing \(mainGroups[2]), \(mainGroups[3]), and \(mainGroups[4])")
            alterArray(starting: 2, ending: 4)
            addDeleteCells(starting: 1, ending: 3, indexPath: indexPath, add: false)
            restaurantIsActive = false
            print("The new array is \(mainGroups)")
        } else {
            mainGroups.insert(contentsOf: restaurantSubGroups, at: indexPath.row+1)
            addDeleteCells(starting: 1, ending: 3, indexPath: indexPath, add: true)
            restaurantIsActive = true
        }

     //   print("There are \(mainGroups.count) in the array and they are \(mainGroups)")

    case "Dining":
        getAnnotations(query: "Restaurant", category: .restaurants, price: .twoDollarSigns)

    case "Fast Food":
        getAnnotations(query: "Fast Food", category: .food, price: nil)

    case "Desserts":
        getAnnotations(query: "Ice Cream", category: .food, price: nil)
}

func addDeleteCells(starting : Int, ending: Int, indexPath : IndexPath, add : Bool) {
    for i in starting...ending {
        let iPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row+i, section: 0)
        indexPaths.append(iPath)
    }
    if add {
        annotationTableView.beginUpdates()
        annotationTableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        annotationTableView.endUpdates()
    } else {
        annotationTableView.beginUpdates()
        annotationTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        annotationTableView.endUpdates()
    }
    indexPaths.removeAll()
}

func alterArray(starting: Int, ending : Int) {
    for i in starting...ending {
        print("In alterArray and removing \(mainGroups[i])")
        mainGroups.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

and here is the console print out when clicked on "Out on the Town" once and then "Restaurants" twice:

```
The items in the array are ["Out On The Town", "Restaurants", "Dining", "Fast Food", "Desserts", "Activities", "Laid Back", "Night In"] and i am removing Dining, Fast Food, and Desserts
In alterArray and removing Dining
In alterArray and removing Desserts
In alterArray and removing Laid Back
The new array is ["Out On The Town", "Restaurants", "Fast Food", "Activities", "Night In"]
```

Any idea as to why it would skip over `Fast Food` and remove `Laid Back`?

To be noted: The cells are being added and deleted correctly but since the contents of the array are not being remove correctly, when a cell goes off the screen and brought back, it is re-created with the incorrect text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the first loop ends the array indices changed

```
 mainGroups.remove(at: i)
```

so the item to be deleted will be in low index (-1) than what should be deleted ,

end of first loop **Dining** is removed  so this

```
["Out On The Town", "Restaurants", "Dining",
"Fast Food", "Desserts", "Activities", "Laid Back", "Night In"]
```

will be (you expect **Fast Food** the next)

```
["Out On The Town", "Restaurants", "Fast Food",
"Desserts", "Activities", "Laid Back", "Night In"]
```

but index 3 is now contains **Desserts**

Comment: ok yea i got it. I just changed alterArray so it takes the starting place and the array of strings i want to remove. It then just iterates through from the starting place to the array.count and removes at mainGroup[starting]. Thanks!